# How to remove bytes/opcodes within IDA Pro database

Tags: ida, deobfuscation

I am dealing with a heavily obfuscated binary, with certain portions of it having an abundance of junk code when it attempts to set a value at certain offsets to esp/ebp.  My question, having identified the junk code from the actual code, is how can I remove the junk opcodes entirely and shorten the disassembly to the direct operation that it is employing?  I have found no delete/remove bytes in the SDK, and short of a processor module, I am not sure if IDA has this capability, which would be a shame if it didn't.

- from:

```
add     ecx, 4  
mov     edi, 32F88Eh    ; junk  
and     edi, 34h        ; junk  
add     edi, 0aB0b2cE6h ; junk  
mov     ebx, 98761234h  ; junk  
mov     [ebp+edi+47652784], ecx; [ebp+0xa0]
```

The manipulations to `edi` are junk in the sense their value is actually static once you apply constant folding to it

- to:

```
add ecx, 4  
mov [ebp+0xa0], ecx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove bytes since that would shift the following opcodes and invalidate all relative jumps/calls. The usual approach in such cases is patching the junk instructions with NOPs (0x90 for x86/x64). You can write a smalls script to do it (e.g. using [`patch_byte`](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/713.shtml)).

Comment: Thanks for response, which in a way, answers my question.  I have been doing it exactly the way you mentioned, but was hoping that if patched correctly, and re-analyzed, the disassembly could be reconstructed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as an additional one to Igor's.

Using nops excessively is perhaps fine for a single routine, or certain instances (at least for me), but the solution I prefer in this case is just cleaning up the code manually outside of IDA, and then adding a separate segment for it into the idb.  That way I don't have to modify the obfuscated code at all, and can have both (clean/dirty) versions, with the clean one becoming the target for further analysis.